# How to fix error arising from passport authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, passport-local-mongoose

I have been trying to figure out why I keep having the error **localhost didn’t send any data** displayed on the browser whenever I try to login
using a registered username and password. Please, what could be the cause of this problem?

Setting up passport

```
const passport = require("passport");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const { Passport } = require("passport/lib");
```

Content of Schema file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: String,
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

passport configuration

```
router.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "It's all about coding!",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Register routes

```
router.get("/register", async(req, res)=>{
   res.render("register");
})

router.post("/register", async (req, res)=>{
   req.body.username
   req.body.password
   var newUser = new User ({username: req.body.username})
   User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
      if(err){
         console.log(err)
         return res.render("register")
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
         res.redirect("login");
      })
   })
})
```

Login routes:

```
router.get("/login", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("login");
})

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "new",
    failureRedirect: "login"
})
```

The route for the page I'm supposed to be redirected to is:

```
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params)
    res.render("new", {post: new Post()});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res)=>{
   User.register(username: req.body.username, req.body.password, (err, user)=>{
      if(err){
         console.log(err)
         return res.render("register")
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=>{
         res.redirect("/login");
      })
   })
})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes